# Circumventing T-Mobile Wireless Modem Restrictions

Tags: networking, router, modem

I have a T-Mobile wireless modem model FAST5688W which has a Tablo Quad DVR attached via the ethernet RJ45.

The Tablo Quad supports remote access via the internet if the modem supports the setup of port forwarding. The T-Mobile modem does not support this.

I was thinking of placing a DDWRT router between the modem and the Tablo to accomplish this goal.  However, the T-Mobile modem allows almost no configuration possibilities.

Is this possible to accomplish my goal and could the router be an just an access point?

Comment: Ask T Mobile if you can have your own router and if they will then set up their modem in bridge mode. My ISP does this for me

Comment: It's highly unlikely the modem/connection even has a public IP address that would allow incoming connections. You're better of investigating alternatives like a reverse tunnel.

Answer (score 2):

After more research it appears like the T-Mobile is not a true modem.

Thus, T-Mobile will never be changing the current definition because it would expose their network.

Comment: This sounds more like a rant rather than an answer.  To make it an answer, please share your research.